# Integral and expected value for multivariate distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, expected-value, integral, truncated-normal-distribution

for the last couple of days I have been struggling with a problem and I was hoping to get some help here.

I have a function that looks as follows:
$$
f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if} \  (x*a+y*b-zc)< 0 \\
  \frac{(x*a+y*b-zc)}{d} & \text{if} \ \frac{(x*a+y*b-zc)}{d} \leq 1\\
  1 & else
\end{cases}
$$
with capped values for f(x,y,z) such that $$0<f(x,y,z)<1$$
My variables are x, y, z are i.i.d with assumed uniform distributions on the interval [0,1].
In order to get the indefinite integral of that function I want to apply the "shadow method". For z:
$$
\frac{(x*a+y*b-z*c)}{d}\geq 0
\iff z \leq \frac{x*a+y*b}{c}
$$
and:
$$
\frac{(x*a+y*b-z*c)}{d}\leq 1
\iff z \geq \frac{x*a+y*b-d}{c} 
$$
For my x:
$$
\frac{(x*a+y*b)}{d}\leq 1
\iff x \leq \frac{d-y*b}{a} 
$$
and
$$
\frac{(x*a+y*b)}{d}\geq 0
\iff x \geq \frac{-y*b}{a} 
$$

As far as I can tell, the indefinite integral should look like this:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\frac{-y*b}{a}}^{\frac{d-y*b}{a}} \int_{\frac{x*a+y*b-d}{c}}^{\frac{x*a+y*b}{c}}f(z)\ dz\ dx\ dy 
\quad 
$$

My questions are now:

1. Is my approach to constructing the integral correct, i.e. did I set the correct borders for my integral?
2. Based on that integral, how can I compute the expected value for the function E(f(x, y, z))?

Any help from the stat masters is highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Seb

Comment: The very first thing to do is to recognize that $(ax+by-cz)/d$ has a Normal$(0,\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}/|d|)$ distribution, thereby reducing this to a univariate problem, whose answer you can [look up](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=truncated+normal+expectation+is%3Aanswer+score%3A1).

Comment: Thank you for the input. Can you point me towards a previously answered question that outlines the process how you get to that? What keywords am I looking for in your search - I struggle to see how to interpret your answer in that regard.

Comment: [The first hit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253453) gets you very close.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153102 has two complete answers. Many of the other hits give answers once you recognize your question is asking for the expectation of the difference of two functions: $\max(0,W)$ and $\max(0,W-1)$ where $W = (aX+bY-cZ)/d.$

Comment: Thanks!! I'll look into that.